# Transpose in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following:

```
Country | StateCity
--------+------------
USA     | MO
USA     | LA
USA     | OH
CANADA  | Ontario
CANADA  | Toronto
```

and am looking to transpose and unify the header with a result like

```
USA CANADA
MO  Ontario
LA  Toronto
OH
```

Comment: That's not transposing and the result isn't a table at all. PIVOT won't work. You could return a result where the field next to `OH` would be NULL or an empty string, but why do that with SQL? It's far easier to do that on the client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But if you want DYNAMIC: **[Sql DEMO](http://rextester.com/FZVY6701)**

First you need a temporal table to create a row_id

```
SELECT row_number() over (partition by [Country] order by [StateCity]) [rn], 
       [StateCity],
       [Country]
INTO temp
FROM State;
```

Then you can go the dynamic pivot route

Create the different columns

```
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.[Country]) 
            FROM temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

Create the pivot query:

```
set @query = 'SELECT rn, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select [rn]
                     , [StateCity]
                     , [Country]
                from temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(StateCity)
                for [Country] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p ';
```

Execute it

```
execute(@query);
```

**OUTPUTs:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to go DYNAMIC

```
Declare @YourTable table (Country varchar(25),StateCity varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values 
('USA','MO'),
('USA','LA'),
('USA','OH'),
('CANADA','Ontario'),
('CANADA','Toronto')

Select USA   =max(case when Country='USA'    then StateCity else '' end)
      ,CANADA=max(case when Country='CANADA' then StateCity else '' end)
 From ( Select *
              ,RowNr=Row_Number() over (Partition By Country Order By (Select NULL)) 
         From  @YourTable
       ) A
 Group By RowNr
```

Returns

```
USA CANADA
MO  Ontario
LA  Toronto
OH
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a client side problem. The result you are looking for is not what is produced from a database query. The query below will get you closer and require less formating client side, however, without iterative processing you are not going to get a result set like that.

```
SELECT
    USA=CASE WHEN Country='USA' THEN StateCity ELSE NULL END,
    CANADA=CASE WHEN Country='CANADA' THEN StateCity ELSE NULL END
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Country,StateCity FROM Table WHERE Country IN('USA','CANADA')
)AS X
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing purposes:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Country (
    Country VARCHAR(10),
    StateCity VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Country (Country, StateCity) VALUES ('USA', 'MO');
INSERT INTO dbo.Country (Country, StateCity) VALUES ('USA', 'LA');
INSERT INTO dbo.Country (Country, StateCity) VALUES ('USA', 'OH');
INSERT INTO dbo.Country (Country, StateCity) VALUES ('CANADA', 'Ontario');
INSERT INTO dbo.Country (Country, StateCity) VALUES ('CANADA', 'Toronto');
```

You can use one of the following solutions:

PIVOT

-- to follow

CASE (I am still working on merging the results to get rid of the NULLS)

```
SELECT 
    USA, 
    CANADA 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN Country='USA' THEN StateCity END AS USA,
        CASE WHEN Country='CANADA' THEN StateCity END AS CANADA
    FROM 
        dbo.Country
) A
    GROUP BY 
        USA, 
        CANADA;
```