# Multiple SQL queries in a single table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL and I was hoping someone from you could help me. 
I have these two queries that I would like to put in the same table in two different columns (if that is even possible).

Sample data:

```
BP Name     Disbursment Date
A           2013          
B           2013
C           2015
A           2015 
B           2016
D           2015
D           2016
E           2015
E           2016
F           2016
G           2016
```

Expected results:

```
BP Name 2016          BP Name 2015
F                      C
G                      D
                       E
```

First query (column "Actual Year)

```
SELECT DISTINCT t."BP Name"
FROM (  SELECT
             "BP Name",
             "Disbursment Date"
    FROM  "SB_MD" 
    WHERE    year("Disbursment Date")  = Year(getdate())
) t LEFT JOIN(  SELECT "BP Name"
    FROM  "SB_MD" 
    WHERE    year("Disbursment Date")  < year(getdate())
) t1 ON t."BP Name"  = t1."BP Name"  
WHERE    t1."BP Name"  is null
```

Second query (would be column "Previous Year")

```
    SELECT DISTINCT t."BP Name"
FROM (  SELECT
             "BP Name",
             "Disbursment Date"
    FROM  "SB_MD" 
    WHERE    year("Disbursment Date")  = (Year(getdate()) -1)
) t LEFT JOIN(  SELECT "BP Name"
    FROM  "SB_MD" 
    WHERE    year("Disbursment Date")  < (year(getdate()) -1)
) t1 ON t."BP Name"  = t1."BP Name"  
WHERE    t1."BP Name"  is null
```

Comment: What data u have and what is your expected result

Comment: Edit your question.  (1) Tag with the database you are using (SQL Server ?) (2) Sample data; (3) Desired results.  And, I don't see a difference between the queries.

Comment: Why do you want it presented like that in SQL? In general you should not worry about presentation in your SQL query. If this is purely for presentation reason then simply do a (single) query which extract all your BP Name and the respective year (2015, 2016) and then let your presentation layer arrange it thusly. If it is not because of presentation, then you're likely solving the wrong problem right now.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen The thing is that I need to have unique BP Names per year and this was the only way I found how to get those results. But now I need to compare number of UNIQUE BPs (Business Partners) in Actual Year with Previous Year. Of course, if there is another way of doing this I am really open to that, as long as it works.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then I think you could do a `GROUP BY` Name and select the `MIN`of the date - that would give you the first year for each name, and then you just select for 2015 and 2016.

Comment: Similar to this question. Using a CASE statement will give you close to what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405286/transpose-in-sql-server-2012/40405547#40405547

Comment: Wow cant believe it was so simple. Thanks a lot @AllanS.Hansen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use full outer join to resolve your issue as below:

```
SELECT A1.[BP Name] AS 'BP NAME 2016',B1.[BP Name] AS 'BP NAME 2015'
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [BP Name] ASC) AS Row#, [BP Name]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT t."BP Name"
        FROM (  SELECT
                 "BP Name",
                 "Disbursment Date"
                    FROM  "SB_MD" 
            WHERE    year("Disbursment Date")  = Year(getdate()
        )) t 
        LEFT JOIN(  SELECT "BP Name"
            FROM  "SB_MD" 
            WHERE    year("Disbursment Date")  < year(getdate())
        ) t1 ON t."BP Name"  = t1."BP Name"  
        WHERE    t1."BP Name"  is null
    ) A
) A1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [BP Name] ASC) AS Row#, [BP Name]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT t."BP Name"
        FROM (  SELECT
             "BP Name",
             "Disbursment Date"
            FROM  "SB_MD" 
            WHERE    year("Disbursment Date")  = (Year(getdate()) -1)) t 
        LEFT JOIN(  SELECT "BP Name"
            FROM  "SB_MD" 
            WHERE    year("Disbursment Date")  < (year(getdate()) -1)
            ) t1 ON t."BP Name"  = t1."BP Name"  
        WHERE    t1."BP Name"  is null
    ) B
) B1 ON A1.ROW# = B1.ROW#
```